# Image web-scraping tool works incorrectly

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am building a web scraping app which gets text info and images from every advertisement on the website. The piece of code responsible for text info(work properly):

```
for a in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "c6e8ba5398--subtitle--UTwbQ"}):
    a = a.text.split(',')
    name.append(a[0])
    sqr.append(a[1])
    floor.append(a[2])
table['Name'] = name
table['Sqr'] = sqr
table['Floor'] = floor
```

The piece of code responsible for images:

```
for a in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "c6e8ba5398--container--Y5gG9"}):
    photo.clear()
    for b in a.find_all("img", {"class":"c6e8ba5398--image--3ua1b"}):
        photo.append(b['src'])
    photos.append(photo)
```

The problem is that i get the list if lists of the same advertisement:

```
[['adv_1_img_1','adv_1_img_2','adv_1_img_3'],['adv_1_img_1','adv_1_img_2','adv_1_img_3']]
```

Meanwhile i need something like this:

```
[['adv_1_img_1','adv_1_img_2','adv_1_img_3'],['adv_2_img_1','adv_2_img_2','adv_2_img_3']]
```

Comment: what is the site url?

Comment: @balderman here you are: https://www.cian.ru/snyat-3-komnatnuyu-kvartiru/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below (see the copy operation before adding the sublist into the main photos list)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import copy

r = requests.get('https://www.cian.ru/snyat-3-komnatnuyu-kvartiru/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

photos = []
photos_sub_list = []
for div in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "c6e8ba5398--container--Y5gG9"}):
    photos_sub_list.clear()
    for _photo in div.find_all("img", {"class": "c6e8ba5398--image--3ua1b"}):
        photos_sub_list.append(_photo['src'])
    photos.append(copy.deepcopy(photos_sub_list))

for sub_list in photos:
    print(sub_list)
```

output

```
['https://cdn-p.cian.site/images/8/239/617/kvartira-moskva-presnenskaya-naberezhnaya-716932893-4.jpg', 'https://cdn-p.cian.site/images/8/239/617/kvartira-moskva-presnenskaya-naberezhnaya-716932894-2.jpg', 'https://cdn-p.cian.site/images/8/239/617/kvartira-moskva-presnenskaya-naberezhnaya-716932895-2.jpg', 'https://cdn-p.cian.site/images/8/239/617/kvartira-moskva-presnenskaya-naberezhnaya-716932898-2.jpg', 'https://cdn-p.cian.site/images/8/239/617/kvartira-moskva-presnenskaya-naberezhnaya-716932896-2.jpg']
['https://cdn-p.cian.site/images2/7/393/857/kvartira-moskva-presnenskaya-naberezhnaya-758393739-4.jpg', 'https://cdn-p.cian.site/images2/7/393/857/kvartira-moskva-presnenskaya-naberezhnaya-758393740-2.jpg', 'https://cdn-p.cian.site/images2/7/393/857/kvartira-moskva-presnenskaya-naberezhnaya-758393742-2.jpg', 'https://cdn-p.cian.site/images2/7/393/857/kvartira-moskva-presnenskaya-naberezhnaya-758393743-2.jpg', 'https://cdn-p.cian.site/images2/7/393/857/kvartira-moskva-presnenskaya-naberezhnaya-758393744-2.jpg']
['https://cdn-p.cian.site/images2/8/453/557/kvartira-moskva-presnenskaya-naberezhnaya-755354822-4.jpg', 'https://cdn-p.cian.site/images2/8/453/557/kvartira-moskva-presnenskaya-naberezhnaya-755354822-2.jpg', 'https://cdn-p.cian.site/images2/8/453/557/kvartira-moskva-presnenskaya-naberezhnaya-755354824-2.jpg', 'https://cdn-p.cian.site/images2/8/453/557/kvartira-moskva-presnenskaya-naberezhnaya-755354820-2.jpg', 'https://cdn-p.cian.site/images2/8/453/557/kvartira-moskva-presnenskaya-naberezhnaya-755354823-2.jpg']
...
```

A shorter version of the code (but not very readable..) below

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.cian.ru/snyat-3-komnatnuyu-kvartiru/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

photos = [[img['src'] for img in div.find_all("img", {"class": "c6e8ba5398--image--3ua1b"})] for div in
          soup.find_all("div", {"class": "c6e8ba5398--container--Y5gG9"})]

for sub_list in photos:
    print(sub_list)
```

Comment: Ok, @balderman, but how can I correctly add them to the dictionary? Because the problem is there too.